# installing air desktop app without internet connection

Tags: flash, air, adobe, desktop, builder

I got an AIR desktop application that I created with the Adobe Flash Builder. Now I wanted to copy it on an USB-stick, and install it on a computer that has no internet connection. Doesn't work though, when I try to do so, I get an error that an updated AIR player is required, and that it can't be updated, since there is no internet connection.

I guess I could just slap the AIR player install files on the USB Stick. Ideally though, I wanted to get the whole thing installed at once, and not forcing the user to install first one thing and then another.

Is there a way to somehow export the AIR player with the AIR application, so that it is automatically installed, without requiring an internet connection? Or have it look first at the USB-stick for install files, instead of checking the internet, and reporting an error? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an "offline installer".  Try this:

- http://forums.adobe.com/message/3382162?tstart=0